# External database hosted on External site such as Godady.in, BigRock.in , is acceped by Google Aap Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to know, that can i use external database for application hosted on Google Aap Engine... 
I have a database hosted on GoDaddy.in. 
Godaddy provides me external access, I can access the database through XAMPP in my system. Which means direct access to database is available.

But the same database is not working on the Google App Engine. 
I want to know whether Google App Engine Accepts external database or it is compulsory to make database on Google Could SQL. 
Not working means
It is showing "Could not Connect to SQL Server "

Comment: Define "not working on the Google App Engine".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing lot of research on Internet and talking with Google Support, I came to know that External Databases are not entertained by Google App Engine.

We have two option to such problem,

1. Either export your database from External site in XML file, and use simpelXMLelement on that file to read it or manipulate it .
2. The Other option is to use Google Cloud SQL, to store your database on Google App Engine  itself. (this will require a credit card, I had used debit visa card of ICICI bank which is working fine on it ).